# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Can't Find File

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am getting the error:

Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Cobb_County_Traffic_Counts.csv'.'

My file is in the main project file (as shown below), so I don't know how it cannot be found.

[image: Solution Explorer]

Here is the code I am running in entirety:

```
 private const string Path = (@"Cobb_County_Traffic_Counts.csv");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadCSV(sender, e);
}

    protected void loadCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<String[]> fileContent = new List<string[]>();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path)) // mind the encoding - UTF8
    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
    {
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true; // if you want
        parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] line = parser.ReadFields();
            fileContent.Add(line);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the path to your file correct? Does your application have the correct permissions?

Comment: Could you give us a little more information? What do you mean by _My file is in the main project file_?

Comment: @RichardEverett here is what the file explorer looks like:

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VBsWKld

as you can see the csv in question is in the project file, should it be somewhere else?

Comment: @mason how would I give it permissions to read a file?

Comment: If this is a file that always ships as part of your website you could include it as an [Embedded Resource](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/319292/how-to-embed-and-access-resources-by-using-visual-c). This has the benefit that you won't need to worry about file location or permissions.

Comment: If you just provide a file name and not a path then it is assumed that it is in the current directory, which is the folder from which the current EXE was run by default. As you can see from the path specified in the error message, the EXE that was run for your web site is IIS Express. You need to do some research and learn how to specify folder paths in a web site.

Comment: (I hope it's ok, but I've edited your question to include the image as this will make it quicker for folk to understand your scenario)

Comment: While `Server.MapPath()` will fix this error for you, you should realize you are parsing constant data on every page load when you don't have to. Do this parsing once in App_Start() to save on computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `Server.MapPath()` to get the actual path. You are resolving the file to IIS installation directory because it is a relative path to where IIS express executable is running from.

```
    List<String[]> fileContent = new List<string[]>();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/" + Path))) // mind the encoding - UTF8
    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
    {
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true; // if you want
        parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] line = parser.ReadFields();
            fileContent.Add(line);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks. I assumed the working directory for the site would be the main project file, obviously my first time using asp.net.